# Can someone explain my rate limit usage

Tags: r, loops, twitter

I've been using r's twitteR package to download tweets and create a data frame from them. But I've been running into the rate limit very quickly, much quicker than I was expecting based on the rate limits posted here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

Here is the code I've been using:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(NLP)
library(twitteR)
library(foreign)
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)
library(base64enc)
library(httr)
library(caTools)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(plyr)

access_token<-"[omitted]"
access_secret<-"[omitted]"
consumer_key<-"[omitted]"
consumer_secret<-"[omitted]"

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)

user.tweets<-userTimeline("@RealDonaldTrump", n=3200, includeRts=T)
master<-twListToDF(user.tweets)
```

I can only run this code on five different users before I hit my rate limit for the 15 minute window. When I use

```
getCurRateLimitInfo()
```

I can see that each time I grab a user's tweets, I use 32 units toward my rate limit. Can anyone explain why this is the case? My best guess at the moment is that each set of 100 tweets I grab counts as one unit towards the rate limit, but if that's the case why isn't that specified in the rate limits documentation?

I'm attempting to grab tweets from hundreds of users, so each time I hit the rate limit the time it takes for this code to run goes up a *ton.* I've developed a for loop that makes use of Sys.sleep() to avoid going over the rate limit, but it still requires a lot of time to finish for every user I'm scraping from.

Comment: The package seems to call [doPagedAPICall](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/blob/97c5cf85b4f22c9d2efea47bfe2e638dba6d9f04/R/comm.R#L111) which fetches records with a [default page size of 100](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/blob/97c5cf85b4f22c9d2efea47bfe2e638dba6d9f04/R/comm.R#L96) so 3200 records == 32 pages of data == 32 api calls

Comment: @MrFlick What happens if he overwrites the function and changes the `maxResults` 100 to 1000, etc?

Comment: Twitter has a [maximum](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) count level of 200 for the userTimeline request